# Can't get wicked_pdf running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I'm just a junior dev. I'm working on getting an old (Ubuntu 8.04, Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.10) app up and running before I update it to current software.

My last issue is that PDFkit is not getting the css. I read that this has been a long standing problem, so after trying a bunch of possible fixes, none of which were successful, I decided to try wicked_pdf.

My problem is I can't get it running. I removed PDFkit.rb and made wicked_pdf.rb in intializers.

```
if Rails.env.production?
  WickedPdf.config = { :exe_path => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64' }
else
  WickedPdf.config = { :exe_path => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf' }
end
```

My dev environment is Ubuntu 16.04, so different wkhtmltopdf libs.

I changed environment.rb removeing PDFkit and substituting wicked_pdf

```
  require 'wicked_pdf'
  config.middleware.use WickedPdf::Middleware
```

I add pdf to Mime types

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

I changed my Gemfile.

```
gem 'wicked_pdf', '~> 0.9.10'
```

When I deploy, my system won't come up. Here is the error.

```
[ E 2020-05-11 20:11:42.8768 31890/T8 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 2-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is ea1f0c0d. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
App 7603 stdout:
App 7603 stdout:
[ E 2020-05-11 20:11:45.3035 31890/Tn age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/xxxxxxxx/current: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: 68a6fb61
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error.LsOzC3
  Message from application: uninitialized constant ActionController (NameError)
  /home/xxxxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/wicked_pdf-0.9.10/lib/wicked_pdf/railtie.rb:17
  /home/xxxxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/wicked_pdf-0.9.10/lib/wicked_pdf.rb:27:in `gem_original_require'
  /home/xxxxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/wicked_pdf-0.9.10/lib/wicked_pdf.rb:27:in `require'
  /home/xxxxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/wicked_pdf-0.9.10/lib/wicked_pdf.rb:27
  /var/www/xxxxxxxx/releases/20200508153214/config/environment.rb:35:in `gem_original_require'
  /var/www/xxxxxxxx/releases/20200508153214/config/environment.rb:35:in `require'
  /var/www/xxxxxxxx/releases/20200508153214/config/environment.rb:35
  /home/xxxxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/initializer.rb:111:in `run'
  /var/www/xxxxxxxx/releases/20200508153214/config/environment.rb:7
  config.ru:1:in `gem_original_require'
  config.ru:1:in `require'
  config.ru:1
  /home/xxxxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
  /home/xxxxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1


[ E 2020-05-11 20:11:45.3167 31890/Ta age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 3-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 68a6fb61. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

It seems to me that it is crashing on the require.

I've written on the wicked_pdf site but it's been more than a week and no replies, maybe because I made a really stupid mistake. But I can't figure it out.

Any ideas or help will really be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are trying to migrated your legacy app to latest, it's not is easy task. And when you want that app up and running, replacing libraries just to get it work would create more problems.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want to change it but it won't find the css. A long known problem. One solution, which many supported, was to switch to wicked_pdf.  This is the last issue stopping me from turning the site over. Any help would be appreciated.